# What's this "function a/<()" in the developer console?

Tags: javascript, notation

While playing with the Developer Console in Firefox, I tried doing this:

```
var a = b => c => c;
```

and then this:

```
a(1)
```

I expected the result to be `function()` (corresponding to `c => c`), but this was displayed instead:

```
function a/<()
```

What is the meaning of this expression? It clearly isn't legal Javascript, since neither `/` nor `<` are valid characters for a function name.

The same happens using the regular notation for functions, i.e. `var a = function(b) { return function(c) { return c; } }`.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

**Edit**: I tried the following

```
var a = b => c => d => d;
a(1)
```

and the result is

```
a/</<()
```

which makes me think it's some kind of lesser-known shorthand notation.

Comment: It returns `function c => c` just as it should in my browser (Chrome) ?

Comment: @adeneo That makes it even weirder.

Comment: That's also specific to the built-in console in Firefox, Firebug is not affected. Intriguing question :)

Comment: ...but `(b=>c=>c)(1)` gives the expected result... weird indeed.

Comment: Does the same with the original function syntax too. Logging the result using `console.dir()`, we can expand the `.prototype` property and see that it has a `.constructor` with that same symbol.

Comment: Don't forget that console output doesn't need to reflect any official language semantics. I wouldn't try to find too much meaning in this. Probably just a display bug.

Comment: Forgive me if this seems trivial, but what exactly does `b => c` do?

Comment: @Adjit: It's a new function syntax. `a = b => c => c` is similar but not identical to `a = function(b) { return function(c) { return c; }; };`

Comment: @Adjit It's called the "fat arrow notation", introduced in ES5. `a => foo(bar)` is equivalent to `function(a) { return foo(bar) }`.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the clarification. So the reason you would use this vs writing out a full function is just personal preference / trying to minimize file size?

Comment: @Adjit: There are various differences. You can read about them [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It's more than just shorthand syntax.

Comment: Is the version of Firefox you're using running ES6 yet?

Comment: @jeff, I'm running latest (43.0) and I can repro this.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi weird...

Comment: What's even more weird is that it actually functions properly - i.e. this `a()(1)` will correctly return 1.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: And if you do a `.toString()` on it, it will correctly show `"function (c) { return c }"`.

Comment: @jeffdill2 If my browser didn't support the ES6 fat arrow notation it'd have run into a syntax error. Indeed, my browser does support it, because `a()(1)` also works for me.

Comment: If you type function a() { return function(){}} and then a(1) it returns the same result a/<(). So it seems unrelated to the arrow notation. Appears to symbolize an anonymous function. Whatever the case, it's wasted a lot of my time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commenters on [the relative issue on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1235455) have pointed out that it's part of a naming convention for anonymous function.

[In particular](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=433529#c9),

> - `a/b` - inner `b` of `var a = function() { var b = function() {}; }`
> - `a<`  - flags `a` "contributor" or basically some helper function which contributes to the function named `a` by being anonymous inside it.

So `a/<()` means that there is an anonymous function was declared in the body of `a`.